# ITMS-90809 error when deploying to Apple. App is on end of life

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, itms-90809

we have and app in end of life (this year) that we want to update.

We use a really old cordova version, and we don't want to spend 1€ in maintenance.

We updated a label and built the new version but the Apple store block us when we try to publish it.

[image]

We used Xcode 11 to build it (we always used xcode 10), could it be the problem?

This is not a new app, why is Apple blocking it?

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b

Comment: and we don't want to spend 1€ in maintenance ... That made my day :)) better 1 half of beer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that UIWebView is now deprecated and you have to update your app to use WKWebView only (via cordova-ios 6+).
There is a big difference when it comes to loading or accessing files with WKWebView, so chances are, you need to spend some time on it.

Read this.
https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/07/18/uiwebview-warning.html

You also might need to update your splashscreen is you use one.

Comment: I understand that UIWebView is deprecated, and it must be removed before december 2020, but the app will die before december, and I don't understand why the store is refusing the upload.
The deadline of April is for the new apps, not the one already in the store.

Comment: This is not up to us. Please validate the answer.